# Database Design for Audit: Many Rows for Answers vs Many Columns

Tags: sql, database-design, query-performance

I am designing a table structure within a SQL Server 2008 database that will hold the results of an audit.  The audit currently has 65 questions and possible answers of 0-4 or N/A.  The table structure I have created to hold this data (still in testing) is described below.  Upon submission, a record is created in the AuditDetail table for each question. If the chosen answer is 0,1, or 2, the user must input details describing why is it low, how to fix, and who is responsible (this creates a record in the AuditIssue table).  Each question is described by two different categories, named QuestionCategory and ItemCategory.

The issue that I am concerned about is that with my current table design, 65 rows are added to the AuditDetail table for each audit that is submitted.  This audit needs to be completed at least 70 times each month (it is used by many departments).  So this table structure will add approximately 4550 rows per month to the AuditDetail table.  I am worried that this may negatively affect performance in the future and want to prevent having to redesign the table structure once i move this into a production environment.

The only other solution that I can come up with is to replace the AuditDetail table with a table that has a column for each question and stores the score for each audit in 1 row, across 65+ columns.

I feel that my current design follows the normalization rules, whereas I do not think creating a column for each question would.  I am almost certain that the questions will change in the future (perhaps many times), including adding/removing questions and changing existing ones.

My searching for answers to this problem lead me to these two sources:
[Many rows or many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201550/which-is-faster-many-rows-or-many-columns)
[Storing Answers In Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227482/store-answers-in-sql-table-with-unique-id-and-store-each-answer-in-columns)

I understand that it would not be ideal to add/remove columns each time a question changes.  **My question is how badly will creating 4550 rows per month affect the performance of my queries?** I do not know if my situation is the same as the one described in "Storing Answers In Columns" because it seems that they were only going to have 100 rows in their table.  **If the performance of the queries is going to be drastically reduced, is there a better table structure that I have not thought of?**

My queries will mostly be used to produce charts which show Total Audits Completed Monthly, Issues Opened vs Closed vs Overdue, Top 10 questions that produce issues, and Monthly or Daily Audit Score (Answer/Total Possible Points Per QuestionCategory or Answer/Total Possible Point).  Each of these charts will need to be sortable by Department, Month, Area, etc.

***Confession:*** I have tend to end up using correlated subqueries to produce some of these charts, which I know already decreases query performance.  I try to work around them, but with me not being a SQL master, I end up stuck in them.

The current table structure i am using for testing is as follows:

```
**AuditMain:**  
--AuditId  <-- PK  
--DeptNumber <-- FK to Dept Table  
--AuditorId  <-- FK to Auditor Table  
--StartDate  
--Area_Id    <-- FK to Area Table  

**AuditDetail**  
--DetailId  <-- PK  
--QuestionId  <-- FK to Question Table  
--Answer  
--NotApplicable  (boolean to determine if they chose N/A, needed to calcualte audit score)  
--AuditId  <-- FK to AuditMain  

**AuditIssue**  
--IssueId <-- PK  
--IssueDescription  
--Countermeasure  
--PersonResponsible  
--Status  
--DueDate  
--EndDate  
--DetailId <--FK to AuditDetail  

**AuditQuestion**  
--QuestionId <-- PK  
--QuestionNumber  (corresponds to the question number on the audit input form)  
--QuestionDescription  
--QuestionCategoryId <-- FK to QuestionCategory  
--ItemCategoryId <-- FK to ItemCategory  

**QuestionCategory**  
--QuestionCategoryId <-- PK  
--CategoryDescription  
--CategoryName  

**ItemCategory**  
--ItemCategoryId  <--PK  
--ItemCategoryDescription
```

Thanks for reading through so much explanation.  I wanted to err on the side of too much information rather than too little, but please let me know if any further information is needed.  I appreciate any and all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Unless your production environment is seriously underpowered, it should be able to hold a half a million rows in a table without seriously degrading performance.  Retrieval performance will be greatly affected by the fields you use for queries and the fields you have built indexes upon.  This can make the difference between witing seconds and waiting minutes.

There's too much detail to go into here, but there are many excellent tutorials on database design.  The best of these titorials will teach you how to design not only for performance, but also for future flexibility, which is just as important.

Your table structure looks pretty good at first glance.